# Adding multiple sets of data to C3 graph stops either from showing up

Tags: node.js, d3.js, graph, c3.js

I've got two things to add to my line graph in C3 - one called 'results' and one called 'lostpackets'. When I put in either one of them into the line graph the graph works and shows the line correctly. This demonstrates that the data is coming through correctly on both sets of data.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get multiple lines on the same graph to work. When I have both on the same graph no results at all show up (the graph axes still show up correctly). I tried to copy [this syntax](http://c3js.org/samples/axes_y2.html).

Here's the code (the commented out line is a single data input rather than having both):

```
chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: container,
                data: {
                    //columns: [results]
                    columns: [
                        [results],
                        [lostpackets]
                    ],
                    axes: {
                        [results[0]]: 'y',
                        [lostpackets[0]]: 'y2'
                    }
                },
                axis: {
                    x: {
                        label: 'Test No.'
                    },
                    y: {
                        label: {
                            text: 'Mbps',
                            position: 'outer-top'
                        },
                        tick: {
                            format: d3.format('.2f')
                        }
                    },
                    y2: {
                        show: true,
                        label: {
                            text: '%',
                            position: 'outer-top'
                        },
                        tick: {
                            format: d3.format('.2f')
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've nested too many times i.e. [[array],[array]] rather than just [array, array]

It should be:

```
                columns: [
                    results,
                    lostpackets
                ],
```

also the axes won't pick up something like results[0] as the property name. You'll need to define it explicitly.

```
                axes: {
                    "results": 'y',
                    "lostpackets": 'y2'
                }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. The reason I'm using results[0] is because I've previously done a 

"results.unshift('Throughput (Mbps)');" 

- perhaps bad practice.

Comment: You could declare a variable outside the c3.generate function like this: `var axisData = {}; axisData[results[0]] = "y"; axisData[lostpackets[0]] = "y2";` and then reference it later i.e. `axes : axisData`